# When exactly does Dataflow Streaming autoscaling start happening?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

So according to the documentation "Dataflow scales up if a streaming pipeline remains backlogged with workers utilizing, on average, more than 20% of their CPUs, for a couple minutes" (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#autoscaling).
Is there an exact timeframe when Dataflow starts scaling up?

Because I tested my streaming job using Streaming Engine (with 1 worker by default) to see if the autoscaling works and if the number of workers go up but after having a CPU utilization of more than 20% for more than 6 min. and also having a backlog of unacknowledged messages from PubSub for the same amount of time (around 6 min.) the number of current workers kept being 1 and no autoscaling happened.

Also regarding the autoscaling chart under Job metrics in Dataflow it says for me: "Current workers: 1, Target workers: 1".
What does "target workers" mean and what is the difference with current workers?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the autoscaling chart.

- *Current workers* - Number of workers currently used by the pipeline
- *Target workers* - Number of workers suggested by the Dataflow autoscaling algorithm. Could be an upscale or a downscale. Pipeline is trying to achieve this.

Regarding time for scaling decision, I don't think there's an exact guarantee provided by the Dataflow service here. Please refer to the Streaming Autoscaling related documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#autoscaling). If you think if there's an issue related to autoscaling, please contact Dataflow support so that that they can look into your specific pipeline.